# Why can't I add strptimes, only subtract?

Tags: python, jinja2

This works fine:

```
{{ strptime(states('input_datetime.music_alarm'), "%H:%M:%S") - strptime("10", "%M") }}
```

But this throws an error:

```
{{ strptime(states('input_datetime.music_alarm'), "%H:%M:%S") + strptime("10", "%M") }}
```

states('input_datetime.music_alarm') equals a time, like 08:00:00

I'm using jinja2 for homeassistant. Here is the error.

```
Error doing job: Task exception was never retrieved
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 239, in _step
    result = coro.send(None)
  File "/srv/homeassistant/lib/python3.5/site-packages/homeassistant/components/automation/__init__.py", line 336, in async_trigger
    yield from self._async_action(self.entity_id, variables)
  File "/srv/homeassistant/lib/python3.5/site-packages/homeassistant/components/automation/__init__.py", line 425, in action
    yield from script_obj.async_run(variables)
  File "/srv/homeassistant/lib/python3.5/site-packages/homeassistant/helpers/script.py", line 158, in async_run
    await self._async_call_service(action, variables)
  File "/srv/homeassistant/lib/python3.5/site-packages/homeassistant/helpers/script.py", line 187, in _async_call_service
    self.hass, action, True, variables, validate_config=False)
  File "/srv/homeassistant/lib/python3.5/site-packages/homeassistant/helpers/service.py", line 72, in async_call_from_config
    config[CONF_SERVICE_DATA_TEMPLATE], variables))
  File "/srv/homeassistant/lib/python3.5/site-packages/homeassistant/helpers/template.py", line 56, in render_complex
    for key, item in value.items()}
  File "/srv/homeassistant/lib/python3.5/site-packages/homeassistant/helpers/template.py", line 56, in <dictcomp>
    for key, item in value.items()}
  File "/srv/homeassistant/lib/python3.5/site-packages/homeassistant/helpers/template.py", line 57, in render_complex
    return value.async_render(variables)
  File "/srv/homeassistant/lib/python3.5/site-packages/homeassistant/helpers/template.py", line 132, in async_render
    return self._compiled.render(kwargs).strip()
  File "/srv/homeassistant/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1008, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/srv/homeassistant/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/srv/homeassistant/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 37, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "<template>", line 1, in top-level template code
TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'datetime.datetime'
```

Comment: The difference between two moments in time is a duration. What would the sum of two moments mean? You probably want to add a duration, which is represented by a `datetime.timedelta`.

Comment: timedelta seems to not be available in jinja2

Answer (score 1):

You MUST use timedelta and you have multiple issue in your code.

1/ Wrong use of datetime.datetime.strptime()

```
>>> import datetime
>>> print(datetime.datetime.strptime("10", "%M"))
1900-01-01 00:10:00
>>> print(datetime.datetime.strptime('08:00:00', "%H:%M:%S"))
1900-01-01 08:00:00
```

You have to parse full datetime to have correct behavior.

2/ You can't sum two datetime

Basically `+` is forbidden to avoid mistake, you need only `-` because you just have to reverse variables in your expression to have your negative timedelta.

```
>>> print(type(datetime.datetime.strptime("10", "%M") - datetime.datetime.strptime('08:00:00', "%H:%M:%S")))
<class 'datetime.timedelta'>
>>> print(datetime.datetime.strptime("10", "%M") - datetime.datetime.strptime('08:00:00', "%H:%M:%S"))
-1 day, 16:10:00
>>> print(datetime.datetime.strptime('08:00:00', "%H:%M:%S") - datetime.datetime.strptime("10", "%M"))
7:50:00
```

You can see in the reverse order this will give you incorrectly `-1 day, 16:10:00` because this can't be handled without error.

3/ You can register timedelta to your template

strptime() is not available by default in Jinja2, so do like it with timedelta()...

Something like that :

```
import datetime
from jinja2 import Template

jinga = Template('{{ strptime(states("input_datetime.music_alarm"), "%H:%M:%S") - timedelta(minutes=10) }} ')
jinga.globals['timedelta'] = datetime.timedelta
print(jinga.render())
```